# Android ADT 21 NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: android, salesforce

I am using Salesforce SOAP API to do a simple login and logout program. I follow the sample code at http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_calls_login.htm.

This code works fine on desktop.

Then, I port it to Android application with the generated jar file (it is `sforce-client.jar`) based on my WSDL file and the `wsc.jar`.

However, when I run it, I got the following error,

> Could not find class 'com.sforce.soap.enterprise.EnterpriseConnection'

referenced from method `salesforceAccess.SalesforceAccess.login`

Do you have any idea what cause it and how to solve it?

Thank you so much for the help.

Ada

Comment: I tried to follow [this link](http://android.foxykeep.com/dev/how-to-fix-the-classdefnotfounderror-with-adt-17). However, the NoClassDefFoundError still exist! Thank you in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I solved the problem!

The steps are, 
1. Build the correct wsc-xxx.jar file from github.com/forcedotcom/wsc (Thank you, Superfell!)
2. Generate the jar file from wsdl using the above wsc-xxx.jar. NOTE: using jdk1.6 to generate the target 1.6 jar. (or whatever match the Android SDK level!!)
3. Import the jars into the Android project.

I was stuck because I was using jdk1.7 to generate the jar file. However, like what this thread ([Android emulator crash: "Dx bad class file magic" / ClassNotFoundException on startup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8748977/android-emulator-crash-dx-bad-class-file-magic-classnotfoundexception-on-st)) said, the Android SDK level is 1.6 (I tried to change to 1.7, the project won't be able to compiled). Therefore, the generated jar file from wsdl won't be able to be packaged in!

The eclipse and ADT doesn't give me any warning or error to tell me. I have to build the Android project from command line (see http://randomsamples.info/blog/phil/android-adt-2101-javalangnoclassdeffounderror-rdimen) and noticed the warning,

```
[dx] trouble processing:
       [dx] bad class file magic (cafebabe) or version (0033.0000)
       [dx] ...while parsing com/sforce/soap/enterprise/EnterpriseConnection.cla
ss
       [dx] ...while processing com/sforce/soap/enterprise/EnterpriseConnection. class
```

What a process!!

Answer (score 2):

Did you add the jar file to the 'libs' directory and check the "Order and Export" checkbox under the properties?

Comment: Yes, I did. See the snapshot of project property and explorer https://sphotos-b.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-prn1/644346_118986294963501_2138676426_n.jpg

Answer (score 0):

If you followed the default instructions for building your jar from the WSDL, then you need to add both this generated jar, and the wsc.jar that you used to generate the jar to your android libs folder. From the error it sounds like you're missing the wsc.jar that you used to generate your jar from. 
Alternatively you can set `-Dstandalone-jar=true` as an option when you generate your jar, and then everything will be in that one generated jar.

Comment: Superfell, I did have wsc.jar in the path (see the picture https://sphotos-b.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-prn1/644346_118986294963501_2138676426_n.jpg). I have no problem for a class (ConnectionConfig) defined in wsc.jar file.

Comment: then your missing the jar generated from the wsdl.

Comment: I just went through this with wsc v27 and it was fine.

Comment: I am trying with wsc-23. Where did you get wsc v27?

Comment: From the picture, the sforce-client.jar is the  jar generated from the wsdl. My program (with wsc-23.jar and sforce-client.jar) has no problem to run on desktop.

Comment: Is there any build.xml for ant?

Comment: Also, this might be a stupid question but just want to confirm: when you say "it was fine", do you mean your application can ran on Android? Thank you.

Comment: i ran my app on a samsung SII (Android 4.0.4) and it was able to login & create a new account record. (WSC builds with Maven, see the readme)

Comment: I am trying to build the wsc jar on Windows. The mvn command failed with the error, [INFO] --- maven-gpg-plugin:1.2:sign (sign-artifacts) @ force-wsc ---
GPG Passphrase: *
*gpg: error loading `iconv.dll': The specified module could not be found.


gpg: please see http://www.gnupg.org/download/iconv.html for more information
gpg: no default secret key: secret key not available
gpg: signing failed: secret key not available