# Dexifying a jar file compiled by JDK 6 gives "bad class file magic" error

Tags: android, bundle, java, dex, jdk6

I am tryig to dexify a jar file using the following command:

```
dx --dex --output=classes.dex JAR_file.jar
```

This gives me the following errors:

```
    trouble processing:
    bad class file magic (cafebabe) or version (0033.0000)
    .....................etc
```

When I searched, I found that they are the same errors that appear in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8538891/bad-class-file-magic-when-using-dx-bat) question

Yes, I was compiling my project with JDK 1.7. So I downloaded JDK 1.6, and changed the setting of my eclipse to make it use JDK 1.6.

I did that by: Window->Preferences->Compiler and then I set the compiler compilance level to 1.6. Finally, I configured the compiler to make it use JRE6 that I downloaded. I clicked OK. I tried to run my project again, and generated the jar file.

When I run the command again for dexifying that jar file. It still shows the same errors. What am I missing?

Note: The jar file is a bundle that I created in my eclipse as a "Plugin" project. Here is a snapshot of the project:

[image]

In the question I am referring to, the accepted answer says if you still have the same problem, then you have to make sure that every single class is compiled right. What does that mean? I tried to compile again and again, but I am still getting the same errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a totally new project (after changing my eclipse compiler to JDK 1.6). Then, the dexifying worked OK.

Answer (score 0):

If you look in Proguard.bat (Android SDK\tools\proguard\bin), you will find the following line:

`call %java_exe% -jar "%PROGUARD_HOME%"\lib\proguard.jar %*`

Replace it with the following:

`call %java_exe% -jar "%PROGUARD_HOME%"\lib\proguard.jar %1 %2 %3 %4 %5 %6 %7 %8 %9`

Mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7866723/dx-bad-class-file-magic-cafebabe-or-version-0033-0000-with-adk14)

Comment: Here's what I have in my Proguard.bat. It is not exactly the same as you mentioned. I feel it's critical file, so I want the exact match and the exact replacement.

@ECHO OFF

REM Start-up script for ProGuard -- free class file shrinker, optimizer,
REM obfuscator, and preverifier for Java bytecode.
REM
REM Note: when passing file names containing spaces to this script,
REM       you'll have to add escaped quotes around them, e.g.
REM       "\"C:/My Directory/My File.txt\""

IF EXIST "%PROGUARD_HOME%" GOTO home
SET PROGUARD_HOME=..
:home

java -jar "%PROGUARD_HOME%"\lib\proguard.jar %*

Comment: I replaced : -jar "%PROGUARD_HOME%"\lib\proguard.jar %*
by: 
-jar "%PROGUARD_HOME%"\lib\proguard.jar %1 %2 %3 %4 %5 %6 %7 %8 %9

but when I wrote the command again, it showed the same error.

Comment: I'll keep looking and see if I can find anything else.

Comment: Do you have any frameworks in your project with sdk level set at 1.7? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8748977/android-emulator-crash-dx-bad-class-file-magic-classnotfoundexception-on-st

Comment: Possibly. I am not sure though. And I don't know how I can check if I have such frameworks or not. So I am looking for a quick fix for everything. But I do have a good feeling that not all the classes are compiled with JDK 6. By the way, you can see in the picture I attached that I am using one library compiled by 1.7. I updated this one to 1.6. But still, it didn't work. i will try more. Thanks for your help. Let me know if you figured anything out.

Comment: I created a totally new project, converted to jar, dexified it. It worked!