# Bad class file magic on dx.bat

Tags: java, android, actionbarsherlock, dex, dx

I need to build my android application from command line(I'm compiling the code using Java7), but when I try to create the dex file I get the following error

```
trouble processing:
bad class file magic (cafebabe) or version (0033.0000)
...while parsing org/holoeverywhere/widget/TimePicker$OnTimeChangedListener.class
...while processing org/holoeverywhere/widget/TimePicker$OnTimeChangedListener.class

trouble processing:
bad class file magic (cafebabe) or version (0033.0000)
...while parsing org/holoeverywhere/widget/TimePicker$SavedState$1.class
...while processing org/holoeverywhere/widget/TimePicker$SavedState$1.class
```

This is how I call dx.bat

```
dx --dex --output=bin/classes.dex bin/classes.jar
```

I have already seen the similar questions ([Bad class file magic when using dx.bat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8538891/bad-class-file-magic-when-using-dx-bat), [Dx bad class file magic (cafebabe) or version (0033.0000) with ADK14](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7866723/dx-bad-class-file-magic-cafebabe-or-version-0033-0000-with-adk14))

But the only solution gave in those questions is **compiling our code using java6**
Since I'm using **ActionbarSherlock** in my project, I have to use **Java7** and I would like to know if by any chance there is a way to create the dex file from class files created by java7

After all IntelliJ is already doing it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well i found the solution here:
http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1966023

I used the following arguments on my javac command, So the generated class files are suitable for Dx command,

```
javac -source 1.6 -target 1.6 ca/tutortutor/utils/Utils.java
```

Comment: @flyingzl your welcome, thank god I was starting to think I'm the only person in the universe which has this problem.