# UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION Error when building with Android and Libgdx

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am trying to build the most recent version of my libgdx app, but haven't had any success in figuring out what is going wrong here. I looked up other errors like it, and tried to see if any of them fixed my problem, but no dice (basically tried changing up the Java versions and uninstalling/reinstalling eclipse and reinstalling all the updates). This problem only started after an update with the android SDK in the last few days from what i can figure (haven't exported the app since Thursday and this is the only thing that I can think of that has changed). Do any of you have any ideas that could help me out? Here is the full stack trace.

```
[2014-05-10 20:04:02 - ***********] Dx 
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
com.android.dx.cf.iface.ParseException: bad class file magic (2f2a2a2a) or version    (2a2a.2a2a)
at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse0(DirectClassFile.java:472)
at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse(DirectClassFile.java:406)
at  com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parseToInterfacesIfNecessary(DirectClassFile.java:388)
at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.getMagic(DirectClassFile.java:251)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:665)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processFileBytes(Main.java:634)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$600(Main.java:78)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$1.processFileBytes(Main.java:572)
at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:284)
at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:166)
at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:144)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:596)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:498)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:264)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:230)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.DexWrapper.run(DexWrapper.java:187)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.BuildHelper.executeDx(BuildHelper.java:786)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.builders.PostCompilerBuilder.build(PostCompilerBuilder.java:597)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$2.run(BuildManager.java:733)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:206)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:328)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.build(BuildManager.java:403)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Project$1.run(Project.java:618)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2345)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Project.internalBuild(Project.java:597)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Project.build(Project.java:124)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.project.ProjectHelper.doFullIncrementalDebugBuild(ProjectHelper.java:1143)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.launch.LaunchConfigDelegate.launch(LaunchConfigDelegate.java:155)
at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:858)
at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:707)
at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin.buildAndLaunch(DebugUIPlugin.java:1018)
at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin$8.run(DebugUIPlugin.java:1222)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53)
...while parsing com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/Batch.class

[2014-05-10 20:04:02 - ***********] Dx 1 error; aborting
[2014-05-10 20:04:02 - ***********] Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1
```

EDIT: I also changed the Proguard file in the Android SDK as described here: [Dx bad class file magic (cafebabe) or version (0033.0000) with ADK14](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7866723/dx-bad-class-file-magic-cafebabe-or-version-0033-0000-with-adk14). That didnt seem to do anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright. I figured this out by looking at the file that was being parsed **"com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/Batch.class"** and assuming that the problem had something to do with a library attached to my libgdx project. I made a new libgdx project and moved over all of the files from my old project to the new one. Things are working fine now and the project builds correctly. Hopefully this helps somebody out in the future.