# bad class cafebabe or version 0034

Tags: java, android, android-studio

After reading other similar questions, I still couldn't find a solution for this. I get the following stack trace which complains about a jar containing a library that I developed, compiled with Java 1.7:

```
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
com.android.dx.cf.iface.ParseException: bad class file magic (cafebabe) or version (0034.0000)
at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse0(DirectClassFile.java:472)
at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parse(DirectClassFile.java:406)
at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.parseToInterfacesIfNecessary(DirectClassFile.java:388)
at com.android.dx.cf.direct.DirectClassFile.getMagic(DirectClassFile.java:251)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:704)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processFileBytes(Main.java:673)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$300(Main.java:83)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$1.processFileBytes(Main.java:602)
at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:284)
at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:166)
at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:144)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:632)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:510)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:280)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)
at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
...while parsing build/classes/main/com/utils/helpers/DateTimeAdapter.class
```

I have the compiler level set to java 7 both in Android Studio and Eclipse and adding sourceCompatibility and targetCompatibility in the build.gradle file did not solve this problem. The path to the JDK is also correctly set in both IDE's.

I found out that 0034 is hexadecimal for Java 8, but it's not even installed in my machine.

I also tried editing proguard.bat, suggested in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7866723/dx-bad-class-file-magic-cafebabe-or-version-0033-0000-with-adk14), with no luck.

Does anyone have any thoughts on this?

Comment: Do you know the version of your android build tools? Java 7 support was only added in version 19.

Comment: I'm using build tools 21.1.2 and compiling to sdk 21

Comment: You may have already seen and tried this, but if not, then well, I guess have a read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24662801/bad-class-file-magic-or-version

Comment: main.com.utils.helpers.DateTimeAdapter? Maybe a lib jar compiled with java 8.

Comment: @Damien I read that already, but thanks for your help

Comment: @Joop I compiled the lib with java 7, I don't have java 8 installed

Comment: `javap -verbose build/classes/main/com/utils/helpers/DateTimeAdapter.class` what does this show ?

Comment: Check whether the file starts with 0xcafebabe and so: http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0544.html

Comment: the command shows _minor version: 0 major version: 51_ which is java 7 according to the link @JoopEggen provided

Comment: And the first 4 bytes are 0xCAFEBABE then?

Comment: yes, they are 0xCAFEBABE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though the class was compiled with Java 7 and the command `javap -verbose` said so, when I opened the .class file in Android Studio, it showed **Decompiled .class file, bytecode version: 52.0 (Java 8)** on the top of the screen.

In the end, deleting and compiling the jar again did the trick.